# Shift Recursive nested child array to parent array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an issue with forming a recursive array. That is shifting the child array nodes to direct elements to a parent array.

like from,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => flare
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [childrenrecursive] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_name] => analytics
                            [parent_category_id] => 1
                            [braincount] => Array
                                (
                                    [count] => 3
                                    [category_id] => 2
                                )
                            [childrenrecursive] => Array
                              (
                                  [0] => Array
                                     (
                                        [id] => 4
                                        [category_name] => sports analytics
                                        [parent_category_id] => 2
                                        [braincount] => Array
                                            (
                                                [count] => 4
                                                [category_id] => 4
                                            )

                                        [childrenrecursive] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                             )

                      )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [category_name] => cluster
                        [parent_category_id] => 1
                        [braincount] => Array
                            (
                                [count] => 4
                                [category_id] => 3
                            )

                        [childrenrecursive] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```

to,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => flare
            [parent_category_id] => 0
            [childrenrecursive] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_name] => analytics
                            [parent_category_id] => 1
                            [count] => 3
                            [category_id] => 2    
                            [childrenrecursive] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [category_name] => sports analytics
                                            [parent_category_id] => 2
                                            [count] => 4
                                            [category_id] => 4                                                  
                                            [childrenrecursive] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [category_name] => cluster
                            [parent_category_id] => 1
                            [count] => 4
                            [category_id] => 3 
                            [childrenrecursive] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

only by moving following child array append to parent in a recursive way.

```
[braincount] => Array
               (
                  [count] => 4
                  [category_id] => 3
               )
```

can anybody help me to format the array like specified.

Comment: Try to produce a [mcve]. The current amount of data in the example is difficult to follow.

Comment: @axiac I tried my best to put but if I minimize  anything there may be chance to misunderstand and more questions may arise.
removed unnecessary keys from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `$input` is the array posted in the question:

```
/**
 * If $value is an array then move the content of 'braincount' one level up 
 * (in $value) then call recursively for all its children.
 */
function moveUp($value)
{
    // Not an array? Nothing to do; return the input value unchanged
    if (! is_array($value)) {
        return $value;
    }

    // Move the content of 'braincount' (if present) one level up
    if (array_key_exists('braincount', $value)) {
        $value = array_merge($value, $value['braincount']);
        unset($value['braincount']);
    }

    // Apply the same operation to all children
    return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $value);
}

// Verify it works
print_r(moveUp($input));
```